# Return counts of grouped record column that match condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called `watched_url_scan_result` and it has a column `watched_url_scan_status`.

It;s purpose is to store scan results for each entry in the `watched_url_record` table.

What I want to do is create a query that gives me a count of each type of status appearing in the `watched_url_scan_status` for each record in the `watched_url_record` table.

I tried:

```sql
select count(wusr.watched_url_scan_status = 'NotFound') NotFound, count(wusr.watched_url_scan_status = 'Found') Found, * from watched_url_scan_result wusr
join watched_url_record wur on wusr.watched_url_record_id = wur.id
where wur.user_auth_custom_id = 4
group by wusr.id, wur.id
```

But it always shows the count as 1 regardless of what string I try to match the status to.  I know I am way off on my approach, can someone point me in right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select wur.id, count(wusr.watched_url_scan_status = 'NotFound') NotFound, count(wusr.watched_url_scan_status = 'Found') Found
from watched_url_scan_result wusr
join watched_url_record wur on wusr.watched_url_record_id = wur.id
where wur.user_auth_custom_id = 4
group by wur.id
```

You can add a `HAVING` clause if you wish to only show rows for `NotFound` and `Found`.

Comment: The count is always 1 still.  I need 1 result per `wur` with status counts added as columns.  This query isn't grouping by `wur.id` or `wusr.id` for some reason - https://prnt.sc/vUqP9w8nIQUE

Comment: In that case remove the `wusr.id` column. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

`count` counts all the not NULLs.  'true' and 'false' are both not NULL.

You could apply a FILTER:

```
select 
   count(*) filter (where wusr.watched_url_scan_status = 'NotFound') NotFound, 
   count(*) filter (where wusr.watched_url_scan_status = 'Found') Found,
   wur.* 
from watched_url_scan_result wusr
join watched_url_record wur on wusr.watched_url_record_id = wur.id
where wur.user_auth_custom_id = 4
group by wur.id
```

Comment: for some reason it will only show a count of 1 and 0 when there are definitely more than 1 result for each record.  I am guessing some issue with it grouping and then only taking 1 record but I can't figure it out.  I think i'll make a new question with a sample dataset

Comment: Of course.  Each group is a group of one, since you are grouping by two primary keys for two tables.

Comment: I've edited to group only by  wur.id.  Had to change the select list too.